# Closure: What did Holmes J. mean by 'molar to molecular actions'?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

https://law.stackexchange.com/q/10900/89 was closed, but why? The quote originates from Holmes's judgment in a US Supreme Court case, which obviously presumes knowledge of law.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the closure was correct.

The collection of Stack Exchange sites is still growing. Sometimes there are questions that are appropriate to more than one site. Sometimes there are questions posed for which there is not currently an appropriate site.

Comment: Sorry, but your comment appears only to state a conclusion, but without any specific supporting reasons.

Comment: @LePressentiment - How about this restatement: **It is not true that for every possible question there exists a Stack Exchange where it is on topic.**  As for "specific supporting reasons" ... I suppose one could argue that it follows from Gödel's Incompleteness Theorem.  Or, more practically, by the definition of what is on-topic at each Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @feetwet Can I please check if you are aware that the quote is from a US Supreme Court judgment?

Comment: Why would that matter? Not every string of written words entails a valid question about linguistics, and not every clause from a legal writing is a legal question. Some questions belong on SE for philosophy, or literature, or metaphor, or psychology. Some questions involving words pulled from legal text still have no home.